# Linux sleep/hibernate predetermined amount of time

Tags: linux, hibernate, ubuntu, time, sleep

Is it possible to have the computer sleep or hibernate for a predetermined amount of time?

And if so, how do I do that on Ubuntu?

Comment: That'd be a bios thing, as it'd be the only thing "running" while the machine's sleeping/hibernating.

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternativly you can use rtcwake, rtcwake is a program in util-linux

```
sudo rtcwake -m mem -s 30
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apmd
```

Example usage:

```
$ apmsleep +1:15            # will suspend for one hour and 15 minutes
$ apmsleep 8:00             # will suspend until 8:00 am
```

You may also want to take a look at the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/apmsleep.1.html)

Comment: i get: apmsleep: Your kernel does not support APM.
apmsleep: Recompile kernel with APM and /dev/rtc support

Comment: I believe what you need to do is disable ACPI (Advanced Configuration and Power Interface) which is newer than APM (Advanced Power Management). See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface)

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2004-July/msg00618.html) answer too

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sleep 3s; sudo pm-suspend
```

You will probably somehow need to ensure that it will not ask you your password.

Comment: That just turns the computer off indefinitely.